# How to assign a Monitoring role to a user (port 8002)

Tags: marklogic

I am using MarkLogic version 8. I would like developers to have access to monitoring history (default port 8002).

What role do I use?

I see a lot of roles in admin console but don't know which one should be used for Monitoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grant the user the [**manage-user**](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/pre_def_roles#id_64197) role, and they will have access to the Monitoring History application.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/config_manager#id_91278

> To access the Configuration Manager page, users must have the role `manage-user`. The role does not grant any privileges to modify configuration settings. Users with the `manage-user` role may:
>
> - Access the Configuration Manager pages to view resources and settings.
> - Export configurations to an ZIP file (with the exception of modules databases).>
> - Import previously saved configurations into the Configuration Manager to view or compare them.
>
>   The `manage-user` role does not grant privileges to edit configuration settings, apply configuration changes from an imported configuration, or to export modules databases. To export the content of modules databases, you must have the `manage-admin` role. However, you won't be able to see modules that you don't have permissions to access. To install (Apply imported) packages, you must to have the `admin` privilege.